# Include files didnt show inside echo query

Tags: php, mysql

Why my included file didn't show? even the theme is read the directory and it is working if I didn't put inside echo.. How can I fixed this?

```
 <?php
 require_once('config.php');
 blalal...
 echo "<?php include('theme/" . $row["themes"]. "/editor/index.php'); ?>"; } } else { echo ""; } $conn->close(); ?>
```

Comment: Why tagged with mysql?..... `echo "<?php include('` won't be working

Comment: Why are you starting and ending the php tags within echo??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include file like this:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

if () {
    if () {

        include('theme/' . $row["themes"]. '/editor/index.php');

    } 
} else { 

    echo ""; 

} 

$conn->close(); 

?>
```

Comment: Don't put parentheses around the argument of `include`. [`include`](http://ca1.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) is not a function and the parentheses are not needed. Even more, if the value returned by `include` is used into a boolean expression, the parentheses fool the reader into grouping the values the wrong way.